# Dropzone.js bootstrap demo not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dropzone.js

i have a working [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)
form upload functionality but i decided to change my form like this [Dropzone.js Bootstrap demo](http://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html)

if i use the snippets from the demo it's not working or i don't know how to make it work

this is my old working Dropzone.js form code

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => route('images.store'), 'class' => 'dropzone', 'files'=>true, 'id'=>'real-dropzone', 'name' => 'addimagetoalbum']) !!}
    <input type="hidden" name="album_id" value="{{$album->id}}" />
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

But how can i make it work using the [Dropzone.js Bootstrap demo](http://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say "It's not working" what specifically is happening or NOT happening ? also what does the console say  ? (f12)

Comment: @Pogrindis when i click submit i get this console error POST http://url.com/gallery/addimage 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: @Pogrindis looking at the laravel log file i see Tokenmissmatchexception error, but i already have <meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" /> in my header

Comment: Are you setting your `headers` in the dropzone ? Can you show us your configuration ? http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-headers

Comment: @Pogrindis hi i just added     headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        },  and its working now but i get a sql error Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'album_id' cannot be null', using form method i could include <input type="hidden" name="album_id" value="{{$album->id}}" /> but how can i do that using that demo snippet